# Looney Tunes episode in which a bird walks and hops, then disappears when passing behind a light pole

Tags: episode-identification, looney-tunes

This is a scene I saw in a Looney Tunes episode somewhere between 2000 and 2010, although I'm not entirely sure in which animated series it was; I would like to believe it was *The Sylvester & Tweety Mysteries*, but I am not entirely sure.

Basically, there is a scene like this where you see the [Minah Bird](https://looneytunes.fandom.com/wiki/Minah_Bird) walk and hop in a city. A dog is following behind him (you see them from a side view). And when they get to a light pole, the Minah Bird disappears, and the dog wonders is confused because there's obviously nothing about the light pole itself.

I suppose that gag is recycled in the drawing below:

[image: Drawing depicting a tank hiding behind a light pole much smaller than it, only part of it being visible]

The way I remember it, that scene happened in some kind of city. They were walking on the pavement, the surroundings looked like buildings (I mean, it was the colours of cements, bricks, greyish or something like that, and there was no tree, at least none that I could remember).

The dog following the bird wasn't the kind that could talk, as far as I remember. He behaved like... a dog, I guess. I'm not even sure what he looked like anymore, though I think it wasn't Hector the Bulldog (maybe a dog that looked more like the Barnyard Dog, willoughby, or maybe a smaller dog like the Frisky Puppy).

The bird was a very minor character in that episode. I'd like to describe it as a cameo appearance, as he wasn't part of the story, just a bird passing by to confuse the dog.

I tried searching "looney tunes bird disappear behind light pole", which is what helped me find that the bird is actually named the "Minah Bird". But I coud not find anything about the scene I remember.

Comment: Something hiding behind a pole that is far too narrow to conceal it is a regular gag in cartoons. But why is this SF?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Last I remember, Looney Tunes was considered on-topic on Sci-Fi Stack Exchange. Can't remember where the Meta post was though.

Comment: @DanielRoseman https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12319/is-bugs-bunny-as-a-whole-on-topic Now that I think about it, the only answer mentions that the sci-fi stuffs are on-topic. But... I'm not entirely sure this is.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Actually, one potentially sci-fi aspect that I remember, is the fact that the bird is capable of impossible feats (the wikia describes him as an "almighty mynah bird"). Two instances I remember are him being able to break open a safe from the inside, and tear apart a mountain in two.

Comment: https://youtu.be/6yd8AR7wcXs?t=168 https://youtu.be/W0IuyFBjeiA?t=153

Comment: Would "toon power" qualifies as sci-fi, though?

Comment: Per consensus on Meta, [Looney Tunes are on-topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12320/98028).

Comment: Could it be "A Mynah Problem" from season 4 of the Sylvester and Tweety Mysteries? Sylvester chases the mynah bird around the roof-space of the reptile house, and there are a couple of occasions when the bird disappears and reappears behind the beams. No dog or light poles though.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez Hmm... That doesn't sound familiar (although watching the scene, I remembered seeing it at least once, even if it's not the one I seem to remember). You made me remember some small details though, I'll add them to the question. Still, my memory might either be fuzzy or mixing stuffs up, so I might accept that as the answer if there really isn't any other scene at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, I suspect that it's from the racist Inki series. https://youtu.be/Djxnw090EeE Do you remember Felix Mendelssohn's [Hebrides Overture](https://youtu.be/zcogD-hHEYs) as background music for the walking bird?

Comment: @Spencer I remember that music, though I can't remember if it was there for that specific scene. To be quite honest, I'm not entirely sure the Inki series was still shown or not, back when I was watching the Looney Tunes. Still, it seems to oftenly play whenever he appears (I just heard it in a short scene in which he appears in Tweety's High-Flying Adventure for example).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is hard to prove a negative, but I have not been able to find an example of the [Minah Bird](https://looneytunes.fandom.com/wiki/Minah_Bird) behaving in exactly the way described in the question.

The Minah bird was introduced as a character in the [Inki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inki) cartoon series:

- *The Little Lion Hunter* (1939)
- *Inki and the Lion* (1941)
- *Inki and the Minah Bird* (1943)
- *Inki at the Circus* (1947)
- *Caveman Inki* (1950)

These are rarely shown now due to the racist depiction of Inki, the African boy, but they can be found fairly easily on the web. None of them contain a scene of the type described. Indeed most of them take place in the jungle (and not in a city), the exception being "Inki at the Circus" which *does* have a dog as a main character, but otherwise doesn't match up with the question.

The Minah Bird did make cameo appearances in later cartoons;

- Tiny Toon Adventures, *Buster and the Wolverine* (1990)
- Animaniacs, *Bad Mood Bobby* (1994)
- The Sylvester and Tweety Mysteries, *A Mynah Problem* (1999)
- *Tweety's High Flying Adventure* (2000)

Again, I didn't encounter the described scene in any of these. Probably the closest match was in *A Mynah Problem* in which Sylvester chases the bird around the zoo, and when they are in the roof-space of the reptile house there are a couple of occasions when the bird disappears and reappears behind the beams. This didn't involve a dog or light poles though.

So I can only conclude that either the scene did not actually involve the Minah Bird, or that my list of cameo appearances is not complete. I have not been able to find any other appearances though.

Comment: Gonna assume that my memory failed me on this one. Maybe it was neither the Minah Bird nor the Looney Tunes. It does make me wonder where that memory possibly came from...

Comment: Just to add that https://allthetropes.fandom.com/wiki/Behind_a_Stick lists a Loony Tunes' character, Cactus Jack, do this behind a cactus but it isn't a bird.

Comment: @Hukk2010 that wiki seems to just be a mirror of [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BehindAStick)

Comment: I've awarded the bounty in recognition of some good sleuthing. I'll post another (open) bounty if someone can find the actual episode that OP is asking about.

Comment: Thank you for the bounty @Clockwork - I hadn't noticed you were giving one. It's not necessary, but it's a lovely gesture ;)